# jquery navigation code does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have written a complete website. I have used my own jquery navigation plugin in it. It works in my localhost, but the hosted version fails to do so. The problem is reported by the firebug is: `mtNav()` is not a function. I don't know what to do. Because the source script of nav plugin is loaded completely. Here is the URL to the site:

http://www.ms-models.com

Just the third item in the top-navigation should include drop-down menus. Please ignore the language, just check the third item of nav menu.

Here is the loaded script:

http://ms-models.com/js/jquery.js

and here is the plugin applied to the navigation bar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('.top-navigation ul').mtNav();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't included the mtNav script on the page. You've only included jquery.

Comment: @kenttam: That isn't actually true; look at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You included a second copy of jQuery between the plugin and the code that uses the plugin.

The plugin was only attached to the first copy, which the second copy overwrote.

Comment: could you please specify which line includes the second jQuery?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi jquery.min.js and you are already including jquery.js but please show some effort to resolve yourself your own problem...

Comment: have you down votted me?